# Change background of two buttons from one onClick?

Tags: android

I am making a quiz app so I will have 4 buttons and when the user clicks the wrong option that one's background will change to red and the right one's will change to green.

I have tried numerous ways including using the XML onClick, the onClick listener. I tried handlers also and nothing worked.

Always the wrong button would be turned red but the right one would never be turned green.

```
....
....
mHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            ansButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    };

}

public void button1(View v){
    if(v.getId() != ansID)
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
public void button2(View v){
    if(v.getId() != ansID)
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
public void button3(View v){
    if(v.getId() != ansID)
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
public void button4(View v){
    if(v.getId() != ansID)
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
.....
.....
```

**EDIT**

On further testing I found that on button1 onClick method I can only tweak button1 and no other buttons even though they are member variables.

Comment: show your Buttons initialize method

Comment: I've used the onClick for each button using button1, button2 ,etc

Comment: Try to first initialize the all buttons then change their colors

Comment: Oh i misunderstood you before. Yeah obviously I initialized all the buttons before. I just didn't use that to change the background.

Comment: use that initialized buttons to change the background

Comment: Tried it but the problem isn't there in making them red, the only thing that doesn't work is after turning the wrong button red the right button doesn't become green for some unknown reason.

Comment: Show your complete code

Comment: I'm sorry the rest of the code has a lot of other stuff I really don't wanna show but this is the part where the problem is that I'm 100% sure off. The red works , green doesn't. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Then try to call this line in every Button click method ansButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

Comment: Tried it again. It didn't work. I removed the handler part and did
<code>public void button1(View v){
        if(button1.getId() == ansID)
            button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
            button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }</code>

Comment: Dude I really want to help you but without seeing the code i can't help you

Comment: Which part do you think matters in this ?

Comment: Initialize and OnclickListener

Comment: in every onclicklistener() you need to find the right button and set it to green

Comment: @KaranMer Tried. Read the edit in the op

Comment: @AkashPopat you have correct answer, you have button with correct answer now what you need to do is compare them somehow, and in every onclicklistener you need to change background of button after comparision

Comment: @KaranMer I am trying to do that. That's the problem cause the background of the right button isn't changing to green.

Comment: @AkashPopat dude all you need to do is compare strings. in every onclicklistener() for every button simply get string from that using gettext now compare it with answer if its true set it to green. simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `ansButton.invalidate()` after changing the background color

Answer (score 0):

When you get an answer, ie. user clicks on a button, call a method which can change colors for all the buttons.

```
changeTheButtonBg(View v){
   b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
   b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   findViewById(ansID).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the color of each button, just the wrong one the user clicked to red and the right answer to green. That is why I have to use either a switch or a if and always the red background is set for the wrong one but the ans green isn't. It only turns green when I click it and when there are no red

Comment: I understand now! Instead of using Handler, you can directly change the button background in button1 method itself right?

Comment: I think the problem is with ansID.. Please check, whether it has proper answer button id only or some other.

Comment: I checked it  using the debugger. The ansID and ansButton are both right but the background isn't changing in it. Weird thing is if Button2 is right and I press button1 then button1 will turn red though button2 wont change. Then if I press button2 then it will turn green.

On further testing I found that on button1 onClick method I can only tweak button1 and no other buttons even though they are member variables.

Comment: Its so weird.  Please try the other solution which I gave.

Comment: Try to call ansButton.invalidate() after changing the background color.

Comment: Yeah invalidate() worked :) write this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a drawable that will be white by default, red when pressed. You can do Red for wrong button and Green for correct buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/red" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

It is done by `StateListDrawable`, represented by `selector` in XML. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Don't want to do it this way because I want that when the red button is shown the right button will turn green.